# Saving output of a function to a text file

Tags: python

I have a function that takes the items in multiple lists and permutates them. So if I have the lists `child0 = ['a', 'b']` and `child1 = ['c', 'd']`:

```
def permutate():
   for i in child0:
      for k in child1:
         print (i, k)

permutate()

#  a c
#  a d
#  b c 
#  b d
```

I'm running into problems with saving the output into a text file. I can't assign a var to the print statement because the output will change every time it runs through obviously, and writing the permutate() function to a text file does nothing. Doing a return instead of print won't run the permutation properly.... any tips on how to print all the permutations to a text file properly?

Comment: Print to file from within the permute function instead of (or as well as) the print function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build a list and return that list object:

```
def permutate():
    result = []
    for i in child0:
        for k in child1:
            result.append((i, k))
    return result

for pair in permutate():
    print(*pair)
```

What you are doing is creating the *cartesian product*, not the permutations.

The Python standard library has a function to do just this already, in [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

list(product(child0, child1))
```

would produce the exact same list:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> child0 = ['a', 'b'] 
>>> child1 = ['c', 'd']
>>> for pair in product(child0, child1):
...     print(*pair)
... 
a c
a d
b c
b d
```

Comment: +1: For the cartesian product stuff. Many get confused with the use of the term *permutation*, when it's just really *ordered combination*.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a file object as an argument, and use `file` argument of `print` function.

```
def permutate(f):
   for i in child0:
      for k in child1:
         print(i, k, file=f)

with open('testfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    permutate(f)
```